# How can I get my sprite to move up and down the screen in FANG? Right now it's just moving back and forth across the screen

Tags: scala

Right now it's just bouncing back and forth across the screen

```
 def moveTriangleTwo {
    triTwo.translateX(triTwoDX)
    if (triTwo.getX < 0.0) {
     // It hit the left wall - go other direction
      triTwo.setX(0.0)    // Place it on left wall
      triTwoDX = -triTwoDX   // Move in opposite direction
     } else if (triTwo.getX > -1) {
      // It hit the right wall - go other direction
      triTwo.setX(-1.0)    // Place it on right wall
      triTwoDX = -triTwoDX   // Move in opposite directinectin
   } 
  }
```

Comment: Change the Y coordinate instead of the X coordinate.

Comment: Thank you so much I actually got that right before I saw this! Do you know how I would make it go horizontally?

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry I meant diagonally, do you know what I have to do?

Comment: change both X and Y at once. The ratio determines the degree. Say, if you add 1 to X and Y you get 45 degree movement, if you add 1 to Y and 2 to X you get a gentler slope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should read about vectors and [coordinate systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system).

The short answer is, on a computer screen, coordinate Y is the vertical axis, starting with 0 on top. The X coordinate is horizontal, starting at 0 on the left and increasing to the right.

For horizontal movement you need to change X, for vertical you change Y, for any diagonal you change both at once.

Comment: BTW, I added this mostly so you can accept the answer and it does not appear as unanswered on the site. Keeps things clean.